# How to tradeoff precision for speed to evaluate sign of dot product of two vectors in C++? (Not hardware specific)

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization

Say I have two vectors of float A and B. I need to find of dot product of A and B, ie. sign(A.B) - if it is positive or negative or 0. Size of vectors is small, less than 100. However,I need to do this extremely fast! 
You can assume all elements in A are floats in range [0,1] and that of B are [-500,+500]. I was looking for exact solution, but approximate solutions will do too if practically do not give a lot of wrong answers (I know, 'lot of' is subjective but I can't put an exact number on it without talking about hardware or implementation)

I explored Pragma compiler directives using -O4 worked the fastest. I explored some more improvements in implementation to make it parallizable based on autovectorization support of underlying processor. Like for avx instruction set, keep 8 independent variable and find dot product, so that all 8 of register capacity is utilized.
But I think we can still be much more faster! Basic idea is, we only need to determine sign of dot product, so there is a lot of scope to tradeoff precision for speed. So i am trying to come up with some mathematical or algorithmic solution to make this tradeoff happen. One Idea i have is to use FFT (Fast fourier transform) to reduce number of multiplications. Another idea I tried to explore was bitwise tricks, but realized bitwise for float is not possible. (IEEE standards are not garunteed when you use fast pragma like Ofast or O3)

You might be thinking why is this such an important to optimize for such minor task but I think it can be a very useful question :-

- Creative Solutions to this problem can be generalized to other similar situations which require precision over speed tradeoff.
- Sign of dot product is a pretty widely applicable sub-problem that shows itself in a dozen scenarios (think complex number manipulation, hyperplane in several ML algorithms, etc)

Comment: how many dimensions?

Comment: @bolov less than 100

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. 100 dimensions,  i.e. a 100-dimensions space with 100 axis, a vector has 100 components to it.

Comment: Lets say |A| = 100 = |B|. By dot product, we multiply ith value in vector A, with corresponding ith value in B, so |A.B| = 100. Is it clear now?

Comment: what is the range of values? are the vectors unitary?

Comment: @ciamej, Range of every element of A is float between [0,1] while range of B is larger say, floats between [-500,+500]. Thanks for your question i'll update it in my question! :)

Comment: is the distribution uniform? do you have outliers? like nearly zero in B?

Comment: maybe you should show existing code, then maybe someone will see room for improvements.

Comment: Also this task looks like a good opportunity to use openCL or something similar.

Comment: what kind of hardware your application will use. There are some compiler flags to specify the hardware. This can provide a huge benefit for performance.

Comment: @ciamej No. nothing is known about distribution. In actual problem I am trying to solve, we have A as constant and we compute many dot products one after another with different vector B to find sign. In this context, each element of B has a more stricter distribution boundary than [-500,500]. For example- B[0] is mostly between [-0.1,0.02] and never goes bigger than say magnitude 2, while B[1] is between [-400,450] and so on. No further distribution is to be assumed, because it doesn't exists.

Comment: It's not clear from your question: do you need an exact solution or an approximate one (which may return the wrong sign or a sign instead of zero in some cases)?

Comment: @MarekR Yes, I have codes but I didn't want to make it about hardware specific improvements but rather about using maths or algorithms to make finding sign of dot product very fast. Thats why I resisted posting code to not mislead the discussion towards language specific optimization.I mentioned them in description only to impart the level of efficiency I am trying to achieve. Hope this is good with you!?

Comment: @ciamej I wanted exact solution but approximate will do too. Sorry, I will this to the question too!

Comment: One obvious optimization in your case would be to use fixed point numbers and use integer arithmetic, have you considered it?

Comment: @ciamej : yes I am using fixed point numbers! I am not sure how to use integer arithmetic here effectively though? type conversion has its overhead so I cannot see how they can be useful at the moment.

Comment: You can store A already in fixed point (since it is used multiple times). I assume you cannot store B in fixed point, can you show us how do you perform the type conversion? I believe this can be really fast if using bit tricks (perhaps worth turning off Ofast).

Comment: @ciamej Yeah thats exactly what i am doing - only storing A in fixed point, it can be preprocessed so its not a cost to my effeciency. And no, i am not using type conversion for int, what i meant in previous comment was that i didn't get how can converting into int be useful enough to compensate for type conversion for applying on B?

Comment: this is more a math question than a C++ one. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Refined title by adding `(Not hardware specific)` The reason for the change is that your title is a good match for search queries such as Google, but the title is misleading in that in a comment you specifically say you don't want hardware specific solutions. The title will show up in the search results and those who will accept a hardware specific solution will see the added part and not use their time to read this. :)

Comment: The math behind dot product is to simple. Problem has `o(n)` complexity and I do not see a room to improve it from mathematical point of view, at least not without a bigger picture.

Comment: @MarekR - That was my immediate thought the moment my eyes encountered the acronym FFT. I actually don't see what real utility a non-hardware solution poses. If someone needed it, it's there. If everyone else could make do with the available throughput, perhaps there's another area effort could be effectivly focused on. Even something that will be ported everywhere - that too will be hardware specific for critical parts of the code. Seems to be a question unaware of real-world concerns.

Answer (score 1):

On modern architectures, the floating point calculation of the dot product already is very fast, 1 cycle will be spent for an addition and 1-2 cycles for the multiplication.

1. I think the performance can only matter when a lot of dot products are calculated.
2. Typically this implies that lots of data will have to be read
3. This implies the runtime will be dominated by the memory bandwidth.
4. This means, big performance gains can only be made by using smaller floating point types, i.e. 32 Bit or 16 Bit floating point numbers.